# Listen to Postgresql Notify channel in FastApi

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, psycopg2

I am currently having a small backend using FastApi and PostgresQl. I want to add some realtime chat capabilities. I use `sqlalchemy` for the database interactions. I read up on Postgres Notify and Listen and it seems like exactly what I need.

But I am struggling to implement it in my application. Do you know how to listen to Postgres channels, preferably using `sqlachemy` and utilizing FastApi's async capabilities?

I tried to find a `sqlachemy` function that implements the desired behavior and I couldn't find one. I found an example with `psycopg2` but I don't know how to implement it in a non blocking async manner.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hmm. Let's just think about this for second - do you mean you want your FastAPI server to handle the events? That's going to be difficult: [it's not something FastAPI is designed for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61755472/9044370) (although one of the linked answers mentions a third party extension that might help). Is it fair to say your question is really about how to write a python programme that will asynchronously listen to a pg_notify channel via SQLAlchemy? Or is integrating it into an existing FastAPI app important?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I think you raised some important questions. Ideally I want my FastApi server to handle the listening. Because architecturally I planned for the clients to connect to my server using websockets, and emitting a notify on my Database so that all server instances know that a new messages was added and it can be delivered to the appropriate clients. I don't care that much about it using SQLAlchemy but rather about it being performant.